# React conditional rendering not updating state in child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a weird problem with conditional rendering in which state isn' going down into a child component.  I have a viewer template, with a PDF viewer component and a Web viewer component (using an iframe).  Depending on what comes back from the server as a `media_type` value, the appropriate component gets rendered.  That's all working fine.

Externally, I have a sibling component responsible for searching inside the content, and in order to do so, it has to pass the search query up to the parent component, which then updates the parent state and then gets passed to the child as a prop.  The reason for this is different content requires different search implementation, which is implemented inside the viewer component.

Apparently, my method of conditional rendering is breaking the search query prop update in the child component.  None of the component update methods are being called when the prop changes, and therefore the search execution never gets called.

The sibling component calls this method in the common parent:

```
/**
 * Search query execution handler.  Passes the state as a prop to the catalog for search
 * execution
 * @param e Keyword or query string from SearchPanel
 */
searchQueryHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
        searchRequest: e
    });
}
```

Parent component render method

```
render() {

    let viewer = <div />;

    if (this.state.link.media_type === 1)
        viewer = <PDF file={this.state.link.id}
                       setOverlayVisibility={this.props.setOverlayVisibility}
                       searchQuery = {this.state.searchRequest}
                       searchMatchHandler={this.searchMatchHandler}
                       searchResultSelection={this.state.searchResultSelection}
        />;
    else if (this.state.link.media_type !== '')
        viewer = <WebViewer link={this.state.link}
                                 setOverlayVisibility={this.props.setOverlayVisibility}
                                 searchQuery={this.state.searchRequest}

        />;

    return (
        <Content>
            <ContentLeft>
                {viewer}
            </ContentLeft>
            <ContentRight>
                <SidePanel institution={this.state.institution}
                           link={this.state.link}
                           searchQueryHandler={this.searchQueryHandler}
                           searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
                           searchResultClickHandler={this.searchResultClickHandler}
                />
            </ContentRight>
        </Content>
    )
}
```

Now, the `searchQueryHandler` method is being hit by the event fired off in `SidePanel`, but none of `componentWillReceiveProps`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, `willComponentUpdate` are called inside `PDF` or `WebViewer`.  I suspect this has to do with the if/else block inside `render`, but not sure how else to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was the parent component was blocked from updating by a `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation that did not take into account the new state of the search query.  As such, it was returning false all the time, and thus blocking propagation of state update to the appropriate child component.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.link !== nextProps.link || this.state.searchRequest !== nextState.searchRequest;
}
```

was the fix.

So simple, and yet so frustrating.

Comment: The double edged sword that is shouldCompUpdate :)